# Insertion in database of type timestamp and data containing apostrophe using ORACLE-11g

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have creater the table successfully as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE TOY_STORE
(
  TOY_STORE_ID NUMBER(3) PRIMARY KEY,
  TOY_STORE_NAME VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
  CITY VARCHAR2(30) DEFAULT 'Delhi',
  PHONENUMBER NUMBER(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  STORE_OPENING_TIME TIMESTAMP,
  STORE_CLOSING_TIME TIMESTAMP
);

ALTER TABLE TOY_STORE ADD CHECK (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CAST (TO_CHAR (STORE_OPENING_TIME, 'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS TIMESTAMP)) > 8 || NULL);

ALTER TABLE TOY_STORE ADD CHECK (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CAST(TO_CHAR(STORE_CLOSING_TIME, 'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS TIMESTAMP)) < 22 || NULL);
```

Now I want to enter data in the table. I executed the following command (here the second data is "Kid's Cave"),

```
INSERT INTO TOY_STORE VALUES(1, 'Kid''s Cave', 'Delhi', 9912312312, 2014-04-01 09:10:12, 2014-04-01 21:42:05);
```

But it showed the following error..

```
ORA-00917: missing comma
```

Please explain

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the dates inside `''`. Try this:

```
INSERT INTO TOY_STORE 
VALUES(1, 'Kid''s Cave', 'Delhi', 9912312312, '2014-04-01 09:10:12', '2014-04-01 21:42:05');
```

**On a side note:**

I will suggest you to use `varchar()` to store PhoneNumbers instead of `Number` datatype

Answer (score 0):

Dates don't have a single quote in your query - Use like so:

```
'2014-04-01 09:10:12', '2014-04-01 21:42:05'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `to_date` to convert string into `date`

```
INSERT INTO TOY_STORE 
VALUES (1, 'Kid''s Cave', 'Delhi', 9912312312, 
        to_date('2014-04-01 09:10:12', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),
        to_date('2014-04-01 21:42:05', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'));
```

you can also use `TIMESTAMP literal`

```
INSERT INTO TOY_STORE 
VALUES (1, 'Kid''s Cave', 'Delhi', 9912312312, 
        TIMESTAMP '2014-04-01 09:10:12',
        TIMESTAMP '2014-04-01 21:42:05');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't the `'`, it's the fact that you are not quoting the date literals. Oracle interprets it as several integer literals with operators between them, and fails because there's no comma separating them.

Surrounding them by quotes (`'`) should work:

```
INSERT INTO TOY_STORE VALUES 
(1, 
 'Kid''s Cave', 
 'Delhi', 
 9912312312, 
 '2014-04-01 09:10:12', 
 '2014-04-01 21:42:05');
```

But it's a bad practice, as it assumes the format matches the database's default date format, which makes your code error prone and unprortable. A better approach would be to explicitly convert these values to `timestamp`s with an explicitly stated format:

```
INSERT INTO TOY_STORE VALUES 
(1, 
 'Kid''s Cave', 
 'Delhi', 
 9912312312, 
 TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-04-01 09:10:12', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 
 TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-04-01 21:42:05', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
```

Comment: I have tried using quotes, but then it's showing error as 

ORA-01843: not a valid month

Comment: @ArpanMona that's exactly why you should explicitly specify a format

Comment: But there is a check constraint on the attributes STORE_OPENING_TIME and STORE_CLOSING_TIME, i.e., STORE_OPENING_TIME should always be after 8am and then STORE_CLOSING_TIME should always be before 10pm. How to specify these then??